# How do I replace invokeAction attributes on link-to components in EmberJs?

Tags: ember.js

I have a piece of code like {{#link-to "schedule.feed" invokeAction=(action "toggleNavigation")}}

Which gives me this error message: Do not use `action` as (action ...). Instead, use the `on` modifier and `fn` helper.ember-template-lint(no-action)

How do I replace action here? I tried changing it to an onclick and using fn but that didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [ember-invoke-action](https://github.com/martndemus/ember-invoke-action) addon for Ember.js has not been updated in some time, and does not work well with the latest Ember Octane code. I would recommend that you template-lint-disable this particular warning for now.

Update: The `on` modifier with the LinkTo component works well in Ember Octane.

```
<LinkTo "schedule.feed" {{on "click" this.toggleNavigaion}}>Feed</LinkTo>
```

See this in action here: https://ember-twiddle.com/c94e0aed7246e86ff81c0fc43b978b1d?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C

Comment: Wondering if `<LinkTo>` support modifiers if used in angle bracket component invocation. If so something like this might work as a native replacement: `<LinkTo @route="schedule.feed" {{on "click" this.toggleNavigation}}>` Haven't tested it myself but it should work in theory. Or did I missed something?

Comment: This seems to work. https://ember-twiddle.com/c94e0aed7246e86ff81c0fc43b978b1d?openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2C Thanks!